# iMacros for loop POS={{k}} k is not holding integer value/storing issue

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

I am having a problem making a loop with iMacros that POS= Relies on k incrementing by 19 ever time, & Store that data. I am having a problem with Holding the k Value through the whole execution, though I know that the var re-sets after iimPlay() is done, and storing it properly. If someone could help me that would be greatly appreciated!

```
var NewLine = "\n";
var PlayMacro;
var StoreData;
var k = 55;
iimSet("k",k);


WebExtract = "Code: ";
WebExtract += "TAB T=1" + NewLine;
WebExtract += "FRAME NAME="+"ext-comp-1006" + NewLine;
for (h = 0; h < 25; h++){
WebExtract += "TAG POS={{k}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:* EXTRACT=TXT" + NewLine;
k =k+19;
}

PlayMacro = iimPlay(WebExtract );
StoreData = iimGetLastExtract ();
alert (StoreData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var NewLine = "\n";
var PlayMacro;
var StoreData;
var k = 55;
WebExtract = "Code: ";
WebExtract += "TAB T=1" + NewLine;
WebExtract += "FRAME NAME="+"ext-comp-1006" + NewLine;
WebExtract += "TAG POS={{k}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:* EXTRACT=TXT" + NewLine;
for (h = 0; h < 25; h++){
k =k+19;
iimSet("k",k);
PlayMacro = iimPlay(WebExtract);
StoreData = iimGetLastExtract ();
alert (StoreData);
}
```

Comment: the first extract will contain the value from (55+19) and not from 55, which is the first position.